# Is wall preparation needed for a border of glass tiles?

Tags: walls, preparation

Can I tile a 3" wide band of 1" x 2" glass tiles on a plaster bathroom wall (not in the shower area)  with no modifications to the wall?

Comment: Thank you for you input. I appreciate the advice concerning the transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Glass tile on wallboard presents no special challenge.
Glass tile on plaster is ok also, as long as it is not too uneven.
You'll need trim on the top and bottom to make the transition look good.

Also as @HerrBag alludes in the comments, glass tile is harder to get right compared to opaque tile.

Comment: I find it easier with glass tiles to do a skim coat of white thinset beforehand (unless the tiles are backed with an opaque coating), to prevent raked thinset from showing the wall color through.